# How to use both ID and slug in Laravel 4 route URL? (resource/id/slug)

Tags: php, laravel-4, seo

I would like to use both ID and slug in my articles route. So instead of `/articles/ID` I want `/articles/ID/slug`.

I don't actually need the slug variable for anything; it's just there to make the URL more readable and SEO, so I'll be using `ID` as identifier for retrieving the articles.

If the URL `/articles/ID` is entered I want to redirect to `/articles/ID/slug`. There has to be an exception for `/articles/ID/edit` since this opens the form for editing the article.

I've googled and looked this site, but I've only found examples of replacing ID with slug, not include both.

**How can I achieve this? And can I use the `URL` class to get the full URL (`/articles/ID/slug`) for an article?**

Current route config:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949298/how-to-add-slug-and-id-url-to-laravel-4-route

Comment: I've seen that post, and he says: "My goal is to continue using Numbers **but also to use Slugs** for better SEO URL's". I want to use both.

Comment: It'll probably still be very close to the first answer to that post. In this case you'll probably be best off without `::resource`, since you need to specify extra parameter for your slug. Something like `::controller('articles/{id}/{slug?}', ArticlesController');` might do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. From the documentation it seems that I can keep the `::resource` route:

_If it becomes necessary for you to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond the default resource routes, you should define those routes before your call to Route::resource:_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661292/add-new-methods-to-a-resource-controller-in-laravel-4/16661375#16661375

Comment: That is correct, depending on where you need those slug; if it's just for when viewing them, then that'll do. If you need the slug on all your `ArticlesController` method, then you'll end up writing all the `Route` definition before your `::resource`, in that instance `::controller` is the more obvious choice. So it comes back to your case.

Comment: I just need it for viewing a single article, all the rest is admin stuff so SEO is not so important. I am a bit curious to how `/articles/ID/edit` will be handled though... I'll do some testing when I get home and post my final solution :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, here is what I ended up doing:

`routes.php`, created a custom route for `show` and `edit`. Used a resource for the rest:

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('articles/{id}/{slug?}', ['as' => 'articles.show', 'uses' =>   'ArticlesController@show']);
Route::get('articles/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'articles.edit', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@edit']);
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController', ['except' => ['show', 'edit']]);
```

Controller, added a `slug` input parameter with a default value. Redirect the request if the slug is missing or incorrect, so it will redirect if the title is changed and return a HTTP 301 (permanently moved):

```
public function show($id, $slug = null)
{
    $post = Article::findOrFail($id);

    if ($slug != Str::slug($post->title))
        return Redirect::route('articles.show', array('id' => $post->id, 'slug' => Str::slug($post->title)), 301);

    return View::make('articles.show', [
        'article' => Article::with('writer')->findOrFail($id)
    ]);
}
```

View presenter, I originally had something in my model class. But moved it to a view presenter class on the basis of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25577174/3903565, installed and used this: https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter

```
public function url()
{
    return URL::route('articles.show', array('id' => $this->id, 'slug' => Str::slug($this->title)));
}

public function stump()
{
    return Str::limit($this->content, 500);
}
```

View, get the url from the view presenter:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <article>
        <h3>{{ HTML::link($article->present()->url, $article->title) }} <small>by {{ $article->writer->name }}</small></h3>
        <div class="body">
            <p>{{ $article->present()->stump }}</p>
            <p><a href="{{ $article->present()->url }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Read more...</button></a></p>
        </div>
    </article>
@endforeach
```