# Laravel: Passing custom URLs with both ID and slug to the view

Tags: php, laravel-4

My articles URL contains both ID and slug, in this format: `/articles/ID/slug`. Only ID is used for record lookup, the slug is just there for SEO and is not stored in the database.

At the moment I am doing this in my view (inside a foreach loop):

```
$url = URL::route('articles.show', array('id' => $article->id, 'slug' => Str::slug($article->title)));
```

To generate the complete URL, e.g: `articles/1/accusamus-quos-et-facilis-quia`, but; **I do not want to do this in the view. I want to do it in the controller and pass it to the view**, but I can't figure out how.

Edit: I am passing an array of multiple articles from the controller to the view, and all of them have unique URLs depending on their respective ID and slug.

Comment: What's the problem? Aren't you already passing $article to your controller? Can't you just create that url in the controller and pass it using with('url', $url)?

Comment: Forgot to mention: I am passing an array of articles to the view, I guess I can enumerate though them all and build of an array of URLs and pass that. Seems a little dirty, I was hoping there was some way I could do something like this with the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of doing something like this is to use a view presenter:

```
{{ $article->present()->url() }}
```

And in your presenter:

```
public function url()
{
    URL::route('articles.show', array('id' => $this->id, 'slug' => Str::slug($this->title)));
}
```

But you can create an acessor in your model:

```
public function getUrlAttribute() 
{
    URL::route('articles.show', array('id' => $this->id, 'slug' => Str::slug($this->title)));
}
```

And use as:

```
{{ $article->url }}
```

Comment: I added an accessor in my model, thank you sir! This is just what I was looking for:) The "view presenter" term is new to me, I'll have to read up on that.

Comment: Starred! Thanks again, that looks very interesting. I definitely see that being useful in many situations :)

Comment: Every time you need to do some kind of modification/formatation/calculation in the content you need to show in your view, you are supposed to do it in a presenter. :)

Comment: I went for the presenter solution, much cleaner:) But shouldn't there be a `return` before the `URL::route`? I can't seem to get it working without it...